# Docker not creating directory

Tags: docker, nfs

I am trying to  create a nfs-server using the below command:

`docker run -d --rm --privileged --name nfs-server  -v /var/folders/nfs:/var/nfs  phico/nfs-server:latest`

After this command when I check /var/folders I don't see nfs folder.

[image]

I logs I see the following :

> Starting NFS server ...
>
> Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel. ...
> (warning).
>
> NFS server started and listening on 172.17.0.2

Docker Preferences shows that docker has File Sharing Permissions for /var/folders
[image]

The logs from pod:
[image]

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: Do you have the folders in the wrong order? When you do `-v /var/folders/nfs:/var/nfs` you map `/var/folders/nfs` on your host computer to `/var/nfs` in the container. You sound like you expect there to be a `/var/folders` directory in the container which there won't be.

Comment: I tried `-v /var/nfs:/var/nfs`. But that did not work either. When I check the logs of the pod I see some errors. I will update the question with the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with MacOS is not resolved but I believe similar solution exists in Mac. But on Ubuntu I had to install nfs-server and nfs-common for it to work.

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
sudo apt-get install nfs-server
```

You can follow the issue on the author's [github](https://github.com/phcollignon/kubernetes_storage/issues/1) page. The author was super helpful and figured out the solution.

Comment: I also had issues with the NFS example but it was connecting the nfs-server to minikube, which was not listed in the `docker network list`. Fortunately, [found out why](https://github.com/phcollignon/nfs-server-minikube/issues/1)